# airflow dag always running in BashOperator dag

Tags: airflow

```
environment:
CentOS 8.1 64bit
mysql  Ver 8.0.17 for Linux on x86_64 (Source distribution)
Python 3.6.8
```

Reason in Task Instance Details shows

```
Task Instance State：
Task is in the 'None' state which is not a valid state for execution.
The task must be cleared in order to be run.
```

The code is as follows.

```
/root/airflow/dags/airflow_hello.py:
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators import BashOperator, PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 7, 22, 0, 0),
    'email': ['xxx@xxx.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}

dag = DAG('airflow_hello', default_args=default_args)

t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='execute_mypyfile',
    bash_command='python3 /root/airflow/dags/python_codes/createfile.py',
    dag=dag)
```

createfile.py under /root/airflow/dags/python_codes

```
createfile.py:
from datetime import datetime

curtime = datetime.now()
# print("now =", curtime)

f = open("1.txt", "a")
f.write("current time:"+str(curtime)+"\n")
f.close()
```

I click Trigger Dag in http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8085/admin/ of 'airflow_hello' Dag. 
but 1.txt is never created under /root/airflow/dags/python_codes or
/root/airflow/dags

Comment: What is in the logs of the BashOperator?

Comment: Kindly share the error message from the logs